# PostgreSQL UTF8 Handling

Tags: postgresql, database

From time time to time my PostgreSQL DB is reporting a strange error:

---

[client] postgres7 error: [-1: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0xb4
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by \"client_encoding\".] in adodb_throw(INSERT INTO 
                                       page_comments(pageid, pagetype, sender_name, sender_mail, sender_url, comment, owner_uid, owner_gid, sortorder, level, parent)
                                       VALUES(
                                           1493,
                                           102,
                                           \'alexis\',
                                           \'xxx@xxx.es\',
                                           \'\',
                                           \'

Next friday i´ll visit Barcelona so in case you need one of this mugs please let me know.

\',
                                           1000,
                                           1000,
                                           1,
                                           1,
                                           NULL
                                           ), )

---

Now, I see that it is coming from the funny apostrophe sign. Yet I am totally confused, as the DB was initialized in UTF8, the web application is serving UTF8 pages, and, moreover, the content is being even utf8_encoded before it is pushed into the database.

Does anybody know how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+00B4, ACUTE ACCENT, is encoded as '\xb4' in ISO-8859-1. In UTF-8, it would be '\xc2\xb4'. So some part of your application changes the encoding to Latin-1. Find and fix that place, and the error should go away.

Comment: thanks! I just figured out that ajax requests were not encoded properly by javascript, thus _some_ symbols got screwed up.